# DD WRT restrict access but exclude subdomain

Tags: firewall, http, http-proxy, dd-wrt

I know it's possible to restrict access to some websites in **Access restrictions** section. I'd like to know if it possible to exclude from restriction subdomain of a site.
For example:

> http://example.com - i want to restrict access to this site
>   http://example.com/section - i want to have access to this section only.

Let me know, please, if it's possible or not.